# Is it possible to use RPM as a poor man's tripwire?

Tags: rpm

I know about `rpm`'s `-V` option that tells me if files installed via RPMs have not been modified, but is there a simple way to get `rpm` to tell me if any files in a given directory were not installed by RPM?  I figure I can use `--whatprovides` on each file, but is there a faster way?

Comment: This would be especially difficult in a directory that might have files from dozens of packages like /etc.  You are better off not trying to use RPM in this way.  What is your aversion to tripwire?  Would it be easier if the package were included?  Look into AIDE.

Comment: Gotta say, that's trying to shoehorn the wrong tool into the job.

Answer (score 4):

why not use the opensource tripwire?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/

Comment: Because all of my experiences with tripwire have been bad and this isn't for intrusion detection, it is for detecting changes made in a production environment.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the feasibility of this I don't think it would be a good idea. The reason is that anyone who could modify a critical file (presumably only writeable by root) could alter the RPM database as well.

Comment: What SvenW says is true.  While in practice I have never seen an attacker attempt to modify the local rpm database, this is a very real problem and the reason that systems like tripwire allow for off-host storage of checksums: in the event of a system compromise you can't trust *any* data stored on the system.

Comment: The RPM database stores information about installed packages. You can query a known good / clean RPM stored elsewhere to list the files it provides. The problem with this is attacking the problem in reverse. You'd have to enumerate all of the installed packages and list the files of each, then diff the file system.  What a nightmare of a process.